# Kubuntu 12.04: get rid of default background between login and desktop ready

Tags: kubuntu, login, desktop-background

I installed Kubuntu 12.04 from scratch and I have successfully changed the login background and used the same pictures for my desktop background. I have 4 screens and for each screen I use a part of a big image (readable for everyone) so that my desktop background appears to be one large image.

However, when starting up and after having completed the login screen, the system shows the (ugly) default background while loading everything and only at the end my desktop background appears. 
Can I change the background that is shown while Kubuntu loads? I have thought of replacing background.png in /usr/share/kde4/apps/ksplash/Themes/Default/ but this is only one file and since I use 4 different images, I don't think this will work.

Where would I have to look to get rid of the default background?

Thanks
-=Wim=-

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Splash Screen – KDE Control Module* and select *None*.

The splash screen that is shown after logging in and before the desktop is ready won't be shown at all, instead the picture from the login screen will be used.